# Django long running task - Database consistancy

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a task running in a thread that will save its input-data after quite some while. Django typically saves the whole object which can have changed in the meantime. I also don't want to run the transaction that long since it will fail or block other tasks. My solution is to reload the data and save the result. Is this the way to go or is there some optimistic locking scheme, partial save or something else I should use?

My solution:

```py
with transaction.atomic():
    obj = mod.TheModel.objects.get(id=the_id)

# Work the task

with transaction.atomic():
    obj = mod.TheObject.objects.get(id=obj.id)
    obj.result = result
    obj.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you don't want to block other tasks doing long operations, you want these operations to be asynchronous.

There exists libraries to do this kind of tasks with Django. The most famous is probably http://www.celeryproject.org/

Comment: A nice project. I don't see any features in celery that help with transactions/optimistic locking or partial save. It'd still be required to either let the transaction run or do a reload. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a partial save via [Django QuerySet's `update` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#update). There's an `update_fields` keyword argument in the [`save` method on instances](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects) which will limit the fields to be saved. However any logic within the save method itself might rely on other data being up to date. There's a relatively new [instance `update_from_db` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.refresh_from_db) for that purpose. However if your save method isn't overridden then both with produce exactly the same SQL anyway. With `update` avoiding any potential issues with data integrity.

Example:

```
num_changed = mod.TheObject.objects.filter(id=obj.id).update(result=result)
if num_changed == 0:
    # Handle as you would have handled DoesNotExist from your get call
```